# Tax calculator issue

Tags: c++, c

I made this program that calculates tax for a range of salaries based on user input. Everything is working fine except for the fact that i cant seem to find a way to make the application ignore the last 3 printf's and just print an error message if the user enters a negative value. I dont want to display the last 3 printf's if the user enters a negative number, instead i want the application to just display "Error: you have entered a negative number" or something of the sort. I'm using visual studio as my compiler, and this is a C application. Help plz. And also please go easy on me its for my programming class in which we are still doing very basic stuff.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    float salary, tax = 0;
    printf("\n\n\tEnter the salary ammount per year: \t\t$");
    scanf("%f", &salary);

    if (salary <= 10000){
        tax=0;
    } 
    else if (salary > 10000 && salary <= 40000){
        tax = (salary - 10000)*0.2;
    } else if (salary > 40000 && salary <= 50000){
        tax = 6000 + (salary - 40000)*0.3 ;
    } else if (salary > 50000 && salary <= 75000){
        tax = 9000 + (salary - 50000)*0.4;
    } else if (salary > 75000.01 && salary <= 100000){
        tax = 19000  + (salary - 75000)*0.5;
    } else if (salary > 100000 && salary >=100000.01){
        tax = 31500 + (salary - 100000)*0.6;
    }



    printf("\nSalary per year:\t\t $ %.2f\n\n", salary);
    printf("Tax ammount per year:\t\t $ %.2f\n\n", tax);
    printf("Salary after tax:\t\t $ %.2f\n", salary-tax);


    getchar();getchar();
}
```

Comment: Only 2 sure things in life: taxes, and CS professors handing out tax calculator assignments

Comment: In general, if you are doing accounting with monetary values, don't use `float` or even `double`. It is best to use `long` or `long long` and count cents or centimes or whatever the smallest unit of currency is. A `float` can not store $0.01 accurately for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already demonstrated you know how to use `if` statements to check whether an `int` falls in a given range.  Just apply this same logic to the output.  Negative numbers are `< 0`.

For example:

```
if(salary < 0) {
    //print error
} else {

    if (salary <= 10000) {
        tax=0;
    } else if (salary > 10000 && salary <= 40000) {
        tax = (salary - 10000)*0.2;
    } else if (salary > 40000 && salary <= 50000) {
        tax = 6000 + (salary - 40000)*0.3 ;
    } else if (salary > 50000 && salary <= 75000) {
        tax = 9000 + (salary - 50000)*0.4;
    } else if (salary > 75000/*.01*/ && salary <= 100000) {
        tax = 19000  + (salary - 75000)*0.5;
    } else /*if (salary > 100000 && salary >=100000.01)*/ {
        tax = 31500 + (salary - 100000)*0.6;
    }

    printf("\nSalary per year:\t\t $ %.2f\n\n", salary);
    printf("Tax ammount per year:\t\t $ %.2f\n\n", tax);
    printf("Salary after tax:\t\t $ %.2f\n", salary-tax);
}
```

On the last `else if`, you really don't need the `if` statement, just the `else`.  Although to be sure (and for clarity) it's fine to include it.  HOWEVER, you definitely don't need `** salary >=100000.01)`  The `>=` will only evaluate to `true` if the `salary > 100000` already evaluated to `true`.  And the `&&` will evaluate to `true` only if both sides evaluate to `true`.  The only way one can be true and the other untrue is if someone enters an odd salary (100000.005), but even if this salary is entered, they still need to be in this tax bracket.

Anyway, your `printf` statements are now contains in the `else` block of the `if(salary<0) {}else{}` block, so they'll only print if the salary was >= 0.

Comment: thanks for the answer. ive been working on this for a while now and you how when you work on something you just get so focused you forget about other stuff. Anyway thanks again for the quick response

Comment: The same error has crept in for `salary == 75.005`. In general, you're re-testing the salary too often. In each `else` branch, you know that the previous condition is false. E.g. if you're in the `else` branch of `if (salary <= 10000)`, you know that `salary <= 10000` must be false, and therefore `salary > 10000` must be true.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but it is always best to let the computer do *all* of the work in calculations. Your code code has a few intermediate results that you must have calculated by hand. Why not let the computer do it? It also lets you easily change the rate structure by editing the key features, the brackets and rates, and not have to worry about the intermediate results.

```
float tax = 0;
struct {
   float basis;
   float rate;
} *ptr, rateStructure[] = 
// list these from high to low brackets
{
 {100000,0.6},
 { 75000,0.5},
 { 50000,0.4},
 { 40000,0.3},
 { 10000,0.2},
 {     0,0.1}
};

ptr = rateStructure;
do {
  float bracket = salary - ptr->basis; 
  if (bracket > 0) {
      tax += bracket * ptr->rate; 
      salary -= bracket; 
  }
  ptr++;
} while (salary);
```

Comment: Not pretty. I'd suggest a `float brackets[2][] = { {100000, 0.6}, {75000, 0.5} .... }; and a for-loop. Macro's are nasty, and not the best way to create a table.

Comment: @MSalters - refactored.

Comment: Looks a lot better. C++ would be a bit shorter, with `for (auto ptr : rateStructure)`. The advantage of such loops is that the compiler has a much better idea how long they'll loop, and can optimize based on that.

Comment: The `auto` feature is only available in C++11. Cool if you have it. I am stuck with IAR EWARM, which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is error prone, and can simplified a lot:

```
if (salary <= 10000){
    tax=0;
} else if (salary <= 40000){
    tax = (salary - 10000)*0.2;
} else if (salary <= 50000){
    tax = 6000 + (salary - 40000)*0.3 ;
} else if (salary <= 75000){
    tax = 9000 + (salary - 50000)*0.4;
} else if (salary <= 100000){
    tax = 19000  + (salary - 75000)*0.5;
} else {
    tax = 31500 + (salary - 100000)*0.6;
}
```